# Stacking background colors with hover and spacing in between list items

Tags: html, css

I want a list with a a somewhat transparent background, and a list item which contains a span that has its own background color.  I want spacing between the li's, but the color to be preserved and the hover to only take the height of the span container(not the full li) The markup is like this:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><span>hello</span></li>
    <li><span>world</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
ul {
  list-style:none;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

li:hover {
  background: gray;
}

span {
  border-top: solid rgba(0,255,0,1) 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
  height: inherit;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,1);
}

span:hover {
  background: gray;   
}
```

The problem comes in only when you try to hover over the element, the height of the li is greater than the span's.  One more constriction is the ul-li markup is set in stone.  I can however change anything inside the li (so a span is not necessary).

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zGzgh/2/

Current State (on hover of the hello list item):

[image]

Still Unacceptable State (on hover of the hello list item)

[image]

Desired State (on hover of the hello list item):

[image]

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: So you want the gray span background to stretch beyond the right side border of it's parent on hover, correct?

Comment: yes, but that part after the right border has to be hoverable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have this figured out. Pseudo-element to the rescue...

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/zGzgh/11/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>
                hello
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>
                world
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

uli, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
    overflow:hidden; 
}
li {
    margin:0 auto;
    background: rgba(0,255,0,1);
    width: 80%;
    height:50px;
    padding-top:10px;
}

span {
    display:block;
    line-height:30px;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}

span:hover,
span:hover:after {
    background:grey;
}

span:after {
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem occur from span rule

remove:

```
border-top: solid rgba(0,255,0,1) 5px;
```

from span element rule,
then i add

```
height:30px;
```

to li element rule

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zGzgh/7/)

Comment: I want spacing in between the list items though.

Comment: Now it doesn't have the green in between the elements like in my desired state picture. edit: Check this out though, I think I'm getting closer:  http://jsfiddle.net/AmZQF/

Comment: yup, of course, because we added margin, you can modify span element rule height to more than 30px if you want it spaced without gap just like before